# COleDispatchDriver error: automation return value coercion failed, DISP_E_TYPEMISMATCH ($80020005)

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, com, mfc

I'm trying to use an auto-generated MFC wrapper class for a C# Interop COM server. The wrapper class was generated using Add->Class->"MFC Class From TypeLib", and it inherits [COleDispatchDriver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fw39e08y.aspx).

Trying to use the wrapper class's `Connect()` method fails with a `DISP_E_TYPEMISMATCH` OLE exception, because the COM server returns `VT_BOOL`, while my wrapper class expects a `VT_VARIANT` (I stepped into MFC sources to check that). This is the code that fails:

```
CSAPTran0 comObj;
comObj.CreateDispatch(__uuidof(SAPTran));
comObj.Connect(L"something");
```

On the other hand, using this code works fine:

```
ISAPTran * comIntf = 0;
HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(SAPTran),NULL, 
    CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,__uuidof(ISAPTran),(void**)&comIntf);
comIntf->Connect(SysAllocString(L"something"));
```

**Update**

This is the code of the auto-generated wrapper's `Connect()` function:

```
BOOL Connect(LPCTSTR sap_string)
{
    BOOL result;
    static BYTE parms[] = VTS_BSTR ;
    InvokeHelper(0x60020005, DISPATCH_METHOD, VT_BOOL, (void*)&result, parms, sap_string);
    return result;
}
```

And this is the screenshot from OLE/COM object viewer:

[image]

Comment: What's the definition of the method in C#?

Comment: I don't have the C# sources right now, but I might be able to obtain it.

Comment: Pretty hard to find a VT_BOOL back in this code.  Consider the possibility that the C# method changed after you generated the MFC wrapper.  Look at the type library with Oleview.exe, File + View Typelib and copy/paste the Connect() method declaration you see into your question.

Comment: OK, the Ole/COM viewer shows that there is a coclass `SAPTran`, which implements an `Connect()` with this signature - `VARIANT_BOOL Connect([in] BSTR sap_string);`.

Comment: Very hard to guess how that got generated, certainly not by C#.  You cannot call this method through the MFC wrapper, it is not idispatch compatible.  COM methods should have an HRESULT return value.  You can only make an early-bound call to this method, your 2nd snippet is valid.  Don't ignore the return value, VARIANT_FALSE is no doubt bad news.

Comment: @HansPassant There is another method `HRESULT Connect(
                [in] BSTR sap_string, 
                [out, retval] VARIANT_BOOL* pRetVal);`, which is a method of a (different one?) `ISAPTran` interface, which has only raw methods, and is a parent/child of the other `ISAPTran` - [this is a picture of the hierarchy](http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=30s7fdg&s=5#.UqH21NIW04A) showed by OLE viewer.

Answer (score 1):

The `ISAPTran::Connect` signature from the OleView screenshot appears to be correct. The other one, `VARIANT_BOOL Connect([in] BSTR sap_string)` is nothing more than a matching `dispinterface` definition, it's a typeinfo for calling the dual `ISAPTran` via `IDispatch` ([late binding](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/138138)).

That's how the MFC-generated wrapper `CSAPTran0::Connect` is trying to call it: via `IDispatch::Invoke`, rather than directly. **Can you show us the generated code for the wrapper**? Does it create a `BSTR` inside (`SysAllocString`) for the string literal you're passing into it (`comObj.Connect(L"something")`)?

**[EDITED]** Put a breakpoint inside `COleDispatchDriver::InvokeHelperV`, on this line:

```
SCODE sc = m_lpDispatch->Invoke(dwDispID, IID_NULL, 0, wFlags,
        &dispparams, pvarResult, &excepInfo, &nArgErr);
```

When `m_lpDispatch->Invoke` returns, is `sc == DISP_E_TYPEMISMATCH` true?

Besides that, if you put a breakpoint (or `Debug.Assert(false)`, for that matter) at the beginning of the C# method implementation, does it even get reached?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, the generated `Connect()` method looks like this: `BOOL Connect(LPCTSTR sap_string)
 {
  BOOL result;
  static BYTE parms[] = VTS_BSTR ;
  InvokeHelper(0x60020005, DISPATCH_METHOD, VT_BOOL, (void*)&result, parms, sap_string);
  return result;
 }
`

Comment: @sashoalm, try calling it like this: `comObj.Connect(_bstr_t(L"something"));`. See if that helps.

Comment: OK, I tried it, but nothing changed. I don't think that casting would change anything, unless you meant it would force a different overloaded function to be called?

Comment: @sashoalm, it's not about casting, BSTR has a somewhat different memory layout from regular zero-terminating string, it stores the length before beginning of the string. Apparently, that wasn't the reason for the error. Check the edit to my answer about breakpoint inside `InvokeHelperV`. Also, are you able to set a breakpoint inside C# code?